# Is using the PCI-E slot's lock essential to securely install a GPU?

Tags: computer-building

I suspect that the lock in my primary slot broke when I removed my former GPU. As the graphics card has a "slip" which is pushed into the PCI-E rail and the card is connected using two screws, does the lock have a vital purpose? And assuming that both of the screws would fail, would the lock even be able to hold the GPU on its own?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a problem, just be sure you tighten the bracket screws. Don't over torque them but you know, a snug tightening.

I know a few people who broke their slot locks and continued to use their slot with no problem. I would take your card out if you plan on physically moving moving your PC to a new location. Minor shifting and sliding of the case should be fine.